# Why does adding a product to a formula with update.formula introduce a vector?

Tags: r

I'm trying to modify model formulas using `update.formula` from the base `stats` package, but adding a new product term does not do what I expected. For example,

```
f <- y~x
update.formula(f, .~.*z)
```

I expected this to return:

```
y~x*z
```

But it returned:

```
y ~ x + z + x:z
```

Can anyone explain this? Is there a way to get the result I expected?

Comment: `y ~ x + z + x:z` is the same as `y~x*z`. The latter is short-hand for the former.

Comment: They don't evaluate the same. If `x<-2` and `z<-3`, `x*z` returns `15` but `x+z+x:z` returns `7 8`.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "evaluate"? My previous comment paraphrases the documentation in `help("formula")`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `help(formula)`. It had the solution to this, which is to use `update.formula(f, .~I(.*z))`.